# Auto increment for group of fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Table Library has  four columns `(counter, studentname,bookname, date)` of type `(int,string,string,datetime)`.
     primary key is `(counter, studentname,bookname)` and counter column has `auto_increment` field set on it.

Above model works good for 1 student where the field counter gets increased for ever book that was borrowed by student.
     When I add a second student, counter starts from where it was left with the previous student. Instead I want counter to start from 1 for every new student that was not already in the system (further counter column has to auto-increase based on the counter column of that particular student)

Question: How can I make a `'counter'` column auto-increment based on a `'student'` column (it seems auto increment works on the table level, but I want auto-increment to work on the column level). How can I enforce this counter column to auto increment based on student

Comment: This (1) won't work and (2) is a bad idea. Anytime you want to have an auto_increment based on multiple columns, your best bet is actually to normalize your data and, if really necessary, implement a counter in your program logic or using a trigger.

Comment: Having a massive primary key can cause problems with indexing. Why not have a plain-old auto-increment column as your primary and add a secondary to cover your three-column case? How are you querying this table where `counter` and the other two terms would be relevant? It sounds like what you want is a sequence generator.

Comment: Here's a question that many people, developers included, for some reason *never* ask themselves - **why**?

Answer (score 0):

First, let me say that I agree with @Ed Cottrell and @tadman about this not beeing a good idea.

However, it can be done if you use MyISAM as your storage engine. See the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html).